# How to filter out null object in react.js

Tags: reactjs, object, filter, null

in the code below i tried to filter out the null objects from the list was collecting from an API.
but i was unable because of the null brand name. Thank you from Zambia.

```
 {brandsQuery.isLoading ? (
    <span>Loading...</span>
    ) : brandsQuery.isError ? (
    brandsQuery.error.message
    ) : (
    brandsQuery.data.filter(brand => brand.brand != ' ').map((filteredBrand) => (
        <div key={filteredBrand.brand} className="form-check">
            <label htmlFor={filteredBrand.brand} className="form-check-label">
                <input
                    className="form-check-label"
                    type="checkbox" 
                    value={filteredBrand.brand}
                    id={filteredBrand.brand} />
                {filteredBrand.brand}
                {console.log('start')}
                {console.log(filteredBrand)}
                {console.log('end')}
            </label>
        </div>
    ))
)}
```

Comment: brandsQuery.data.filter(brand => brand.brand) - this would be enough if the brand.brand is any false value like undefined, false, empty string , 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// To filter out false values

brandsQuery.data.filter(brand => brand.brand)
```